# Implement shared loading screen in angular

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services, angular2-components

I have a lot of components which needs to load data from a web service. During the loading I want to show a global loading indicator which overlays the complete site. It is possible that multiple components load data at the same time.

### The Service and the Service-Subscriber

To synchronize a common loading-indicator I wrote a Service:

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Observer } from "rxjs/Observer";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalLoadingIndicatorService {

    private _isLoadingSource = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    public isLoadingObservable = this._isLoadingSource.asObservable();

    public get isLoading(): boolean{
        return this._loadingProcessCount > 0;
    }

    private _loadingProcessCount: number = 0;

    public addLoadingProcess(): void{
        this._loadingProcessCount += 1;
        this._isLoadingSource.next(this.isLoading);
    }

    public removeLoadingProcess(): void{
        this._loadingProcessCount -= 1;
        if(this._loadingProcessCount < 0){
            throw "Negative _loadingProcessCount is not possible.";
        }
        this._isLoadingSource.next(this.isLoading);
    }
}
```

In my `AppComponent` (it is the root of my app) I stored the `Observable<boolean>` in a property `isLoadingObservable`:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { GlobalLoadingIndicatorService } from "../Services/GlobalLoadingIndicatorService.js";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs/Subscription";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Component({
    selector: "app",
    templateUrl: "/Templates/App"
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    constructor(
        private _globalLoadingIndicatorService: GlobalLoadingIndicatorService
    ) { }

    public isLoadingObservable: Observable<boolean>;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.isLoadingObservable = this._globalLoadingIndicatorService.isLoadingObservable;
    }
}
```

In my HTML-Template, I bind `isLoadingObservable`:

```
<div *ngIf="isLoadingObservable | async">Loading...</div>
```

### Add/Remove Loading-Processes

Now, when I need a global loading indicator, I inject the service and use the methods:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    constructor(
        private _myService: MyService,
        private _globalLoadingIndicatorService: GlobalLoadingIndicatorService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {        
        this._globalLoadingIndicatorService.addLoadingProcess();
        this._myService.getData().subscribe(
            x => {
                this.userGroups = x;
                this.userGroup = x.length > 0 ? x[0].id : null;
                this._globalLoadingIndicatorService.removeLoadingProcess();
            },
            error => {
                alert(error);
            }
        );
    }
```

### The Problem

In some (not in all) components I get a run time error:

> `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: `'[object Object]'`. Current value: `'true'`.

I read about this error and found out that I changed a variable which would end in a UI Update during a Angular-Hook-lifecycle.

Among others I found this article: [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

Because of this article I do not like the solution with `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges` or `setTimeout`.

How can I change my **Global**-Loading-Indicator to solve this issue?

---

### Further Information

I also found an issue thread on GitHub: [`ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` when changing a component value in `afterViewInit` `#14748`](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14748#issuecomment-320139557)
Especially the solution from *minuz* at 4th August: I cannot see a real difference from my code. Why does it work for him but not for me?

Comment: I have the exact same problem for months. Never had an idea how to solve it. If you find it, don't forget to share it.